# Programmatically embed Kanji in Textfield

Tags: flash, embedded-fonts

In the "Embed...Character Embedding" window in the Flash environment, you can select to embed Japanese Kanji. Does anyone know of a way to embed the same using a `TextField` created with Actionscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I ended up finding out that the best way to support Kanji (in my case) was to *not* embed the font at all and just use the _sans option in the TextField.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a font symbol in your library and assign a linkage class (in this case "Font1"):

```
var myFont:Font = new Font1();
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.font = myFont.fontName;

var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
myTextField.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
myTextField.embedFonts = true;
myTextField.text = "Hello World!";
addChild(myTextField);
```

See article on [Embedding fonts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts/)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this with succes:

```
    package
{


        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.display.TextField;
        import flash.display.TextFieldAutoSize;

        import flash.text.TextFormat;
        import flash.text.AntiAliasType;



        public class EmbedFontTest extends Sprite
        {



                [Embed(source="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\ARIAL.TTF", fontFamily="Arial")]
                private var _arial_str:String;

                private var _arial_fmt:TextFormat;
                private var _text_txt:TextField;



                public function EmbedFontTest()
                {
                        super();

                        this.initEmbedFontTest();
                }



                private function initEmbedFontTest():Void
                {
                        this._arial_fmt = new TextFormat();
                        this._arial_fmt.font = "Arial";
                        this._arial_fmt.size = 40;

                        this._text_txt = new TextField();
                        this._text_txt.embedFonts = true;
                        this._text_txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
                        this._text_txt.defaultTextFormat = this._arial_fmt;
                        this._text_txt.text = "Test Arial Format";

                        this.addChild(this._text_txt);
                }
        }



}
```